# toBeValid test failed when aria-invalid="false"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am writing a test for a button's valid case when several conditions are met. Here is a code snippet:

```
it("some conditions are met -> button shows valid", async () => {
    // some conditions are met;
    render(
      <Provider>
        <MyComponent />
      </Provider>
    );
    const button = screen.getAllByRole("button")[0];

    fireEvent.click(button);

    await waitFor(() => expect(button).toBeValid());
```

Test failed but the error msg is:

```
expect(element).toBeValid()

    Received element is not currently valid:
      <button aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-invalid="false" aria-labelledby="topics-label topics-toggle-button" aria-required="true" class="css-1rryzs9" id="toggle-button" type="button" />
```

I am confused how it failed when aria-invalid="false".

Any idea why this happened?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `aria-required="true"` or enter some value to the input.